# LBPH Recognizes Only Trained Images (OpenCV Android)

Tags: java, android, opencv, face-recognition, lbph-algorithm

My preprocessing steps:

1. Crop the detected face
2. Apply greyscale on image
3. Resize to a standard size (100x100)
4. Histogram Equalization filtering

After applying the aforementioned steps on both training and testing images, LBPH seems to be only recognizing faces that has been only trained before. If I tested another untrained image of the same person that previously had images trained in LBPH, it fails to recognize it.

Is OpenCV LBPH recognizer even accurate? I really don't care if it displays the right label at this point, what I just care about it is to know that a person is found (only the trained ones). I'm starting to doubt it and think that it was a waste of my time. High expectations I guess... :/

Comment: sounds like overfitting. How many training samples per person and how many different persons did you provide during training?

Comment: I only trained for 1 person, with 5 images. But I have read somewhere that LBPH does not require as much images per person to work properly at least compared to other Recognition Algorithms like Eigen & FisherFace.

Comment: have a look at https://johanneskinzig.de/index.php/files/21/Benchmarking-OpenCV/3/BenchmarkingPaper.pdf where some people share their experiences

Comment: I just searched what overfitting is (yeah I know I'm stupid), this is exactly my problem. :/ . Gonna check out the link you  provided.